# How often is appropriate to destroy objects?

Tags: object-oriented, actionscript

I know this is hard to answer without examples, so I'm looking for general principles or guidelines here. I'm thinking within the realm of small- to medium-sized mobile games and apps.

I've read a few times the object reuse is a touchstone of creating efficient programs. So, I generally strive to reuse everything possible. But, then I came to realize that every object I'm keeping around has to exist *somewhere* in memory, so it's begun to seem **inefficient**. I've thought it would be fine, as long as I'm not trying to render the objects' visual or auditory aspects. And I've feared that construction and re-construction of these objects would be too expensive to perform every time I just want to toggle their presence.

Let's say, for instance, I've got a GUI comprised of 30 different objects that each represent a screen state-- buttons, panes, text, a background, maybe some animated UI components. Does it seem more sensible to initialize and de-initialize these objects, keeping them around in memory, but disabling their rendering, animations, etc? Or should I just be destroying these things and re-creating them?

Other examples of things I keep around might be game objects like non-playable characters, weapons, items, etc.

Comment: Sounds like you want to read up on Singleton Pattern and Disposable (C# uses IDisposable) and when to use each, and when to use neither.

Comment: No, he doesn't. He needs to read on Premature Optimization.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Premature Optimization - Just Say No!**

Having multiple objects is an important abstraction over the raw memory access you would be left with if not for Object Oriented Programming.

**Creating an object, is reasonably inexpensive operation on even the most modest hardware available.** You should not avoid it by default.

The special case, where a new object creation is expensive justifies the use of [Object Pool Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern).

Sharing memory between similar objects, frequently found in games, can be helped with the [Flyweight Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

As a simple example, using a compiled language (C#, Java, C++) on a modern PC, you can create **millions** of simple objects in a single second.

**Remember**: Any optimization should be done only after you have **determined that your code is slow**, and only to the **parts that are slow**.